# issue in reading a serialized object

Tags: android, serialization, udp

I am trying to create a client-server android app in which I want to transfer a file using a UDP protocol. Till now I am able to transfer the file and receive the acknowledgements for the packets.

Now I want to add the sequence numbers to the with the data in the packet. I have tried to do the following:

- Create a ByteArrayOutputStream.
- Wrap it in an ObjectOutputStream
- Write data to the object using `writeObject()`

Serialized class includes:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private int seqNo;
private byte[] data;
private boolean ack;

public Message(int seqNo, byte[] data, boolean ack) {
    this.seqNo = seqNo;
    this.data = data;
    this.ack = ack;
}
```

Client Side

```
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[500];
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

while((numBytesRead = inputBuf.read(fileBytes)) != -1) {
//DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(fileBytes, fileBytes.length);
if (os == null) {
    os = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
}
        Message msg = new Message(++seqNo, fileBytes, false);   
    os.writeObject(msg);
    os.flush();
    os.reset();

    byte[] data = outStream.toByteArray();
    atagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    clientSocket.send(packet);
    }
```

Server Side

```
byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
try{
    DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);                                                      
        serverSocket.receive(incomingPacket);
    byte[] data = incomingPacket.getData();                 
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);                             
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);

    if (is == null) {
           is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    }
    Message msg = (Message) is.readObject();
    System.out.println(msg.getSeqNo());
    out.write(msg.getData(),0,msg.getData().length);
      }
```

The problem that I am facing is

1. I am receiving the same sequence number for each packet (i.e. 1)
2. I am not sure about the buffer size for the incoming packet, as I am using 500 bytes at Client side and 1024 at
   the Sever. And if I take 500 bytes at both the sides I get an EOFexception.

I would really appreciate if you could suggest better ways to implement the same thing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Message msg = new Message(++seqNo, fileBytes, false);

Here you are assuming that the prior read() filled the buffer. On the last read() before end of file it almost certainly won't, and it isn't guaranteed to fill it any time, only to transfer at least one byte.

You should be passing the read count 'numBytes' to this constructor, and it should create a byte array of that size, and copy only that many bytes into it.

Other issues:

- It is impossible for 'os' to be null at the point you're testing it.
- Ditto 'is'.
- You should be creating a new ObjectOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream per datagram.
- Java Datagrams keep shrinking to the size of the shortest datagram payload received so far. You  must either create a new one per receive, or at least reset its length before each receive.
- you need a larger buffer at the receiver because of ObjectOutputStream overheads.
- I don't believe this code presently works at all, let alone that you keep getting the same sequence number. More likely you keep getting the same *message,* because you're ignoring an exception somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply EJP. Can you please help me understand "You should be passing the read count 'numBytes' to this constructor, and it should create a byte array of that size, and copy only that many bytes into it."

Comment: I don't see why it's necessary. I would expect any competent programmer to be able to code directly from that specification. Take it a piece at a time.